# GIPHY Favorites to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, animated-gif, giphy, giphy-api

Does anyone know of a way to import GIPHY Favorites into Google Sheets? I hate the fact that I can't share my favorites with anyone else, and that they're completely private. Wondering if there's a way to use the GIPHY API to import all of them into a single Google Sheets file.

Thanks for your help,
Spencer

Comment: It looks you can. https://gist.github.com/gargomoma/ed70f2860f24ec25e358f0da7be3dcb8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Apparently Giphy API does not support this type of granularity to a query.

  - Although you could retrieve Gifs owned by an account via the [Search endpoint](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/api/endpoint#search), there is no way to query which gifs were "favorited" given an account.
  - I've also found this related feature request [ticket](https://github.com/Giphy/GiphyAPI/issues/174) on their Github repo.
- Regarding importing it to Sheets, once you find a way to get the information you'd like to be displayed in Sheets, you can make the HTTP request via Apps Script and add it to the respective cells as you like.

  - To perform a HTTP request in Apps Scripts, refer to the [UrlFetchApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) documentation
  - To insert the information retrieved by the HTTP request to a cell, refer the [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) method for an example.